# MarqueeLabel not working , its just showing as an UILabel on screen

Tags: ios, iphone

I have included the files from the link https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel in my project

```
MarqueeLabel *continuousLabel2 = [[MarqueeLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 440, self.view.frame.size.width-20, 20) rate:10 andFadeLength:10.0f]; 
continuousLabel2.tag = 101;
continuousLabel2.marqueeType = MLContinuous;
continuousLabel2.animationCurve = UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear;
continuousLabel2.continuousMarqueeExtraBuffer = 50.0f; 
continuousLabel2.numberOfLines = 1; 
continuousLabel2.opaque = YES; 
continuousLabel2.enabled = YES; 
continuousLabel2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft; 
continuousLabel2.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.234 green:0.234 blue:0.234 alpha:1.000]; 
continuousLabel2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
continuousLabel2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.000]; 
continuousLabel2.text = @"This is another long label that scrolls continuously with a custom space between labels! You can also tap it to pause and unpause it!"
[self.view addSubview :continuousLabel2];
```

I have pasted the above code in my project but the text just appears as an UILabel and not as marquee. Please advice

Comment: Did you import Quartzcore Framework in your project?

Comment: yes its already imported

Comment: Well, I tested the code and it works for me.. I guess you may need to change the width of your continuousLabel2.. Try reducing it and see if that makes an impact..

Comment: tried reducing the width but still getting same result

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Put this at the end of your code**

```
 [continuousLabel2 restartLabel];
```

**OR**

```
[self performSelector:@selector(startlabel) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
-(void)startlabel{
        [continuousLabel2 restartLabel];
}
```

Comment: yups this solution is working . thanks . can u explain what was the problem in my code

Answer (score 0):

I use `resetLabel` to start the marquee animation.

Also don't forget to set the `labelize` property to `NO`. i.e.

```
[self.marqueeLabel resetLabel];
self.marqueeLabel.labelize= NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of Github documentation of Marquee Label
"MarqueeLabel tries its best to automatically begin scrolling when appropriate, but sometimes the way your view/view controller appears onscreen can trip it up.
Using the restartLabel instance method to "manually" start scrolling on a MarqueeLabel"

[yourMarqueeLabel restartLabel];